# How to mantain or export folds when copying a file in Vim

Tags: vim, code-folding

Every time I copy a file the folds are lost. I understand why this happens, but I can''t figure out out to "export" or "maintain" the folds. Any suggestions? (otherwise I have to rename the view files one by one if I copy a entire folder).

EDIT: I'm folding lines by writting for instance: `:1,80 fo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the lovely manual, `:help foldmethod`.

With the manual folds you are using:

> The manual folds are lost when you abandon the file.  To save the folds use
>   the `:mkview` command.  The view can be restored later with `:loadview`.

Or, you can `set foldmethod=marker`, and then `:fold` will litter your file with `{{{` and `}}}` to indicate where the folds are. Since the default value is `manual`, you'll have to set it to `marker`, either in a modeline or in your vimrc.

Comment: It will litter your file with whatever markers you set in foldmarker, just to be complete.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `:saveas`.

It will make a copy of your file and its view into a new file with its own view.
Your original file and view will be left untouched.

```
:edit original.md
:saveas copy.md
```

The only downside is that if you have file marks (A-Z), they will be moved (not copied, moved) to your new file.